# Deploying J2EE web application on windows server 2008 R2

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, web-deployment

I have developed a web application on my local system and Iw ant to deploy it on the server where other user from my group can also access the application. The IP address of my server is 10.1.2.34. I can access the application from browser within server but when I try to access the application from other computer within same network, it page dosent exists. The tomcat server on eclipse is configured with localhost and here is my servlet code for database connectivity    `conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.1.0.25:3306/textfiles","root","sathya");`

Should I have to configure any other so that other people within the network can also access my application.

Comment: You will have to add Firewall Inbound rules for port 3306 in your Win Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Please check that your Server IP is correct and see if there is any network problem. Try to ping the server and create a tcp connection to the port to validate that there is no problem in the network. Note : *The client and server should be in the same network*. What is the URL you use to access it?

Comment: @Octopus I tried the method whichuser3145373 suggested and it worked for me..thanks for your help